# Veritcally aligning text within Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could anyone please help me; how do I center text vertically within a responsive grid?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>YOU CAN'T</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're vertically centering a DIV of unknown height. You can use a CSS transform like this:

```
.v-center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/106258

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have an example, I can admit adjusting the margin-top will do it

http://jsfiddle.net/F7rHQ/

```
h1{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**Update**
some adaptations to the first option considering font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/zgwnP/

Comment: But what will happen when the font size will bigger and the div height is bigger too? Then the `margin-top: 10px;` will not make it align vertically centered

Comment: You are right. My fault. I'm not sure if this is the best option, but I could centralize it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/zgwnP/. Margins always trick me.

Answer (score 0):

By vertically aligning it, I'm guessing you mean centered text? If so:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h1 class="text-center">YOU CAN</h1>
</div>
```

If you mean to center your text within a section, I would specify my margin-top in different media queries